Does the ordering of fields in a composite index matter for performance?
I have a Firestore query which is taking a while to execute (> 4 seconds). The query is structured as follows:
db
  .collection('testCollection')
  .where('fieldA', '==', 1)
  .where('fieldB', '==', 2)
  .where('fieldC', '==', 3)

The automatically-generated composite index is fieldC (ASC), fieldB (ASC), fieldA (ASC) (we'll call this Index Alpha). Note that the data is distributed as follows:

fieldA (highest cardinality)
fieldB (next highest cardinality)
fieldC (lowest cardinality)

If I manually create a composite index fieldA (ASC), fieldB (ASC), fieldC (ASC) (we'll call this Index Beta), will this result in a faster query execution, since this better utilises the data cardinality?
Also, I notice that Firestore allows both indexes to be present at the same time. In what cases will Firestore choose Index Alpha over Index Beta for a query, and vice versa?

Have you read the documentation about this?

Where did you check that when you perform that query, the Index Alpha is automatically-generated and not Index Beta? Please respond using @AlexMamo
